# How to Unregister EasyHook.dll, EasyHook64.dll, and EasyLoad64.dll

Tags: c#, hook, easyhook

I'm using `EasyHook` dlls & performing `DoDragDrop` API hooking, everything is working fine, but how to release following 3 dlls

1.`EasyHook.dll`
2.`EasyHook64.dll`
3.`EasyLoad64.dll`

these dlls are hooked to `explorer.exe` even after closing my application, they release once I restart my explorer.exe

So far I did't find any solution, so I posted it here, Please help me to solve this issue.

Below is my DLL `Run()` code snippet.

```
public void Run(RemoteHooking.IContext InContext, String InChannelName)
    {
        try
        {
            dragDropHook = LocalHook.Create(LocalHook.GetProcAddress("Ole32.dll", "DoDragDrop"), new DragDropDelegate(DoDragDropHook), this);

            dragDropHook.ThreadACL.SetExclusiveACL(new Int32[] { 0 });

            File.AppendAllText(logFilePath, "Run : LocalHook Created" + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Interface.ErrorHandle(ex);

            File.AppendAllText(logFilePath, "Run Exception :" + ex.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);

            return;
        }

        Interface.IsInstalled(RemoteHooking.GetCurrentProcessId());

        RemoteHooking.WakeUpProcess();
        File.AppendAllText(logFilePath, "Running " + Environment.NewLine);
        while (checkforDesktopExe())
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        if (dragDropHook != null)
        {               
            // Remove hooks
            dragDropHook.Dispose();
            // Finalise cleanup of hooks
            LocalHook.Release();
            File.AppendAllText(logFilePath, "Disposed " + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot unload the managed assemblies EasyHook.dll or EasyLoad64.dll as they are loaded into the default .NET AppDomain and as far as I know .NET does not support unloading assemblies from here. Your hook assembly will be getting unloaded because EasyLoad sets up a new AppDomain for this purpose.

In theory it may be possible to unload the native EasyHook64.dll using Win32 API, however it is used by the EasyHook.dll managed assembly and I’m not sure what would happen if you tried to rehook/inject. Considering it is not possible to unload the other two I don’t see any point anyway.